# Java MAP assistance

Tags: java, hashmap

First off, I've only recently started to use Java, so what might seem obvious to others may not appear so to me.

I'm trying to implement a Quiz application and one of the stipulations is that I read the questions from an external file and store the questions in a MAP structure.

I've looked into this and it appears that a MAP stores a key and a value...

Am I right in thinking that I can store an idetifier as the key and then the rest of the information as the value, even though the rest of it consists of 4 elements of two differing data types (2 ints, a string and an array of strings)?

If my assumtion is correct, how would I implement that, as any documentation I have found resembles the following:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> questionMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Any assistance or nudges in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

The Question class currently consists of (I've remover the getters and setters to save space on here:

```
public class Question {
    public int identifier;
    public String type;
    public String question;
    public String[] options;
    public int answer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First create a class to hold your question information, then use it for the values in your Map, e.g.:

```
HashMap<Integer, Question> questionMap = new HashMap<Integer, Question>();
```

Comment: You haven't defined what `Question` is.

Answer (score 2):

> the rest of it consists of 4 elements of two differing data types (2 ints, a string and an array of strings)?

This sounds like an Object that you'd want to write your own class for

```
public class Data {
    int id:  // optional 
    int a, b;
    String c;
    String[] d;
}
```

Then your Map would be of the type `<Integer, Data>`, and I would suggest a `TreeMap` if you want ordered questions

Answer (score 0):

> Am I right in thinking that I can store an idetifier as the key and
>   then the rest of the information as the value, even though the rest of
>   it consists of 4 elements of two differing data types (2 ints, a
>   string and an array of strings)?

No, both key and value have to be a of a single data type.
What you usually would do in that case is create your own data structure that encapsules your data:

```
public class Question {
    private int id;
    private int score;
    private String question;

    // Constructor, Getters & Setters
    //....
}
```

Then you can use that dataType as a Value

```
Map<Integer, Question> questionMap = new HashMap<Integer, Quesiton>();
```